# How can I fix I2C communication problem in Cortex-M4

Tags: cortex-m

firstly I use mcp4725 DAC which uses I2C communication. In debug mode when I continue line by line code works and conversion result can be seen o.scope however when I press run, code runs until done label however conversion is not happening I mean I can't see the result in o.scope.How can I solve this problem.Thanks!

```
            ;LABEL          DIRECTIVE   VALUE       COMMENT
            I2C0_MSA        EQU         0x40020000 ;MASTER SLAVE ADDRESS
            I2C0_MDR        EQU         0x40020008 ;MASTER DATA ADDRESS
            I2C0_MCS        EQU         0x40020004 ;MASTER CONTROL AND STATUS REGISTER
            FIRST           EQU         0x20000000 ; FIRST MEMORY ADDRESS
            ;***************************************************************
            ;***************************************************************
            ; Program section                         
            ;***************************************************************
            ;LABEL      DIRECTIVE   VALUE       COMMENT
                        AREA        DAC, READONLY, CODE
                        THUMB
                        EXPORT      I2C_DAC ; Make available
                                    ;A2=0 A1=1 A0=0
            I2C_DAC     PROC
                        LDR         R0,=FIRST ;ADDRESS OF FIRST SAMPLE
                                                ;PRE-LOAD NECESSARY REGISTER VALUES
                        LDR         R2,=I2C0_MSA;SLAVE ADDRESS
                        LDR         R3,=I2C0_MDR ;DATA
                        LDR         R4,=I2C0_MCS ;CONTROL STATUS
                        LDR         R6,=0x03 ; ---0-011 START AND RUN SET
                        LDR         R8,=0x04 ;---0-100 STOP TRANSMISSION
            loop        CMP         R0,R7    ;R7 HOLDS LAST WRITTEN SAMPLE ADDRESS+1 WHEN IT IS REACHED TERMINATE SERIAL COMMUNICATION
                        BEQ         done    ;OTHERWISE KEEP SENDING DATA
                        LDRB        R1,[R0],#1 ;LOAD ADC RESULT TO R1 
                        LSL         R1,#4     ;MULTIPLY BY 16 TO CONVERT 8-BIT REPRESENTATION TO 12-BIT REPRESENTATION      
                        AND         R9,R1,#0xF00;MSB 4BITS
                        LSR         R9,#8;FIRST DATA
                        AND         R10,R1,#0xFF ;SECOND DATA
                        LDR         R1,=0x01 ;---0-001 KEEP TRANSMITTING
            idle        LDR         R5,[R2]
                        BIC         R5,#0xFF ;CLEAR MSB 8 BIT
                        ORR         R5,#0xC4 ;GIVE 1100 DEVICE CODE 010 A2,A1 AND A0 BITS TRANSMIT OPERATION
                        STR         R5,[R2] ;STORE SLAVE ADDRESS
                        LDR         R5,[R3]
                        BIC         R5,#0xFF
                        ORR         R5,R9
                        STR         R5,[R3] ;WRITE FIRST DATA
            busbusy     LDR         R11,[R4] ;POLL CONTROL AND STATUS REGISTER
                        ANDS        R11,#0x40 ;ISOLATE BUS BUSY BIT
                        BNE         busbusy
                        STR         R6,[R4] ;START TRANSMISSION
            busy_1      LDR         R11,[R4] ;POLL BUSY BIT
                        ANDS        R12,R11,#0x01; ISOLATE BUSY BIT
                        BNE         busy_1
            error       ANDS        R12,R11,#0x02;ISOLATE ERROR BIT             
                        BEQ         continue
                        STR         R8,[R4];TERMINATE TRANSMISSION IN ERROR CASE
            busy_2      LDR         R11,[R4] ;POLL BUSY BIT
                        ANDS        R12,R11,#0x01; ISOLATE BUSY BIT
                        BNE         busy_2          
                        B           idle
            continue    LDR         R5,[R3]
                        BIC         R5,#0xFF
                        ORR         R5,R10
                        STR         R5,[R3];WRITE SECOND DATA
                        STR         R1,[R4];KEEP TRANSMITTING
            busy_3      LDR         R11,[R4]
                        ANDS        R12,R11,#0x01 ;ISOLATE BUSY BIT
                        BNE         busy_3
                        ANDS        R12,R11,#0x02 ;ISOLATE ERROR BIT
                        BEQ         continue1
                        STR         R8,[R4] ;STOP TRANSMISSION IN ERROR CASE
            busy_4      LDR         R11,[R4] ;POLL BUSY BIT
                        ANDS        R12,R11,#0x01; ISOLATE BUSY BIT
                        BNE         busy_4          
                        B           idle
            continue1   STR         R8,[R4] ;STOP TRANSMISSION
            busy_5      LDR         R11,[R4] ;POLL BUSY BIT
                        ANDS        R12,R11,#0x01; ISOLATE BUSY BIT
                        BNE         busy_5
                        B           loop
            done        BX          LR
                        ENDP
                        END
```

Answer (score 1):

After writing intended voltage and command to DAC you should put some real relay(1-2sec) in your code to see effect on o.scope